# Javascript Event Listeners issue

Tags: javascript

I have one javascript file that is referenced in all my files.

I've been trying to add JS to two files: `index.php` and `login.php`.

Here is the code I am using in my javascript file:

```
function addListeners() {
    document.getElementById('first').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('second').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('third').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('fourth').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('fifth').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
}


function change_border() {
    this.style.borderColor = "#37FDFC";
}

}
window.addEventListener("load", addListeners);
```

The above code works perfect and is targeting a form on `index.php`.

**The problem is when I reference the Javascript file from `login.php` and change the code to this:**

```
function addListeners(){
    document.getElementById('first').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('second').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('third').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('fourth').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById('fifth').addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById(ID_FROM_LOGIN.PHP).addEventListener("focus", change_border);
    document.getElementById(ID_FROM_LOGIN.PHP).addEventListener("focus", change_border);                
}


function change_border()
{
    this.style.borderColor = "#37FDFC";
}

}
window.addEventListener("load", addListeners);
```

For some reason, when I add two new listeners for `login.php`, the only code that works is the code for `index.php`, unless I add them at the beginning of the listeners; then `login.php` works and `index.php` doesnt.

I have asked several people and noone can give me an appropriate response.

Comment: open console and check error.

Comment: What is `ID_FROM_LOGIN.PHP`? Do you generate it in PHP? If so, please post generated JavaScript here.

Comment: `ID_FROM_LOGIN.PHP` are input id's from the `login.php` file

Comment: Keep your browser developer console open while you're working!!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just changing the border with css (:focus selector) on most of these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not checking to see whether any of those calls to `.getElementById()` return `null` (meaning that no matching element is found). When that happens, your code will throw an exception and fail.

Add simple tests:

```
var first = document.getElementById('first');
if (first) first.addEventListener("focus", change_border);
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, but why would that matter? Even if some listeners are null because of lack of ID, shouldnt the script continue and Work for the next lines

Comment: No it won't, because you're trying to call the `.addEventListener` method of `null` which will throw an error.

Comment: @RobertTossly If the function returns `null`, then you're trying to do the equivalent of `null.addEventListener( ... )`, which will throw an exception (as you can verify for yourself by typing that in your browser's developer console).

Comment: Hmmm, ok, this solved my issue. I am either going to make a separate JS file for each page, or use if statements to provide appropriate event listeners depending in file path.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give all the border colour changing elements a class?
If so you could rewite your function:

```
function addListeners()
{
 var awesomeelements=document.getElementByClassName('awsomenewclassname');
 for(var i=0;i<awesomeelements.length;i++)
 {
  awesomeelements[i].addEventListener("focus", change_border);
 }                
}
```

Then it doesn't matter what elements are on the page as long as they have the class .awesomeelements.